# R Shiny input selected all does not select any input

Tags: r, shiny

Using R Shiny to build an interactive dashboard, I want to select all choices in the input by default. For some reason, when running the app, all choices are still deselected though.

Code (UI):

```
library(shiny)

data <- read.csv2("data.csv")
input <- as.list(data$v1)

checkboxGroupInput("input",
                   label = "input",
                   choices = input,
                   selected = input)
```

Any suggestions what could go wrong? Data is just a normal dataframe, input a normal list.

Answer (score 0):

All seems to be fine with me, even with the `as.list` which I dont think is necessary. Maybe it conflicting with the name you're using `input`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

select1 <- unique(mtcars$cyl)

ui <- fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput("select1",label = "input",choices = select1,selected = select1))
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]

Comment: The as.list() itself was the problem. Removing the function, giving a vector as input, works fine. Thanks for your help ;)